# Simple Calculator Help (C++)

Tags: c++, calculator

I wrote a very simple calculator program in C++ and it works fine! But can someone explain how I can modify this code such that it will be able to add more than 2 numbers at once?

So instead of doing 2 + 2 for example, I want users to be able to do 2 + 2 + 2. But every time I try, it just adds the first two "2"s and gives 4, no matter how many + 2 you type after it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// input function
void Input (float &x, float &y);

float a=1.0, b=1.0, result;
char operation;

int main ()
{
    cout << "A simple calculator \n\n";

    cin >> a >> operation >> b;

    Input (a,b);

    cout << result << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}


void Input (float &x, float &y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;

    switch (operation)
    {
    case '+':
        result = x + y;
    break;

    case '-':
        result = x - y;
    break;

    case '*':
        result = x * y;
    break;

    case '/':
        result = x / y;
    break;

    default:
        cout << "Improper operation. Please input a correct calculation        operation: \n";
        cin >> a >> operation >> b;
        Input (a, b);
    }
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: You have no loop reading more than 2 numbers and a single operator - why is `operation` a global and not an argument to the evaluation function `Input`?

Comment: try this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696503/im-have-trouble-with-logic-of-simple-calculator-with-one-textbox-on-java-eclip

Comment: Why do you expect this code to perform two calculations? You retrieve two operands and one operation (cin >> a >> operation >> b). Show us the code where you attempt to perform two calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is thought so you are asking the input for three elements: 2 numbers and their operator (represented as a character).

Let's say you are taking just one shot. If you want to use more operators and numbers you have to develop a simple parser which should continue acquiring input until a end token is found, probably end of line in your case.

To do this I would change your approach concerning data acquisition and calculation. You have to simple options:

- Perform your calculations online: That is, to keep a partial result and update it after each input.
- Gather all your input in a data structure representing it and then perform all the calculations.

For example, if you decide to implement the first option, this incomplete code may help you:

```
float Input (float &x, float &y, char operation)
{
    float result;
    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
        result = x + y;
        break;

        case '-':
        result = x - y;
        break;

        case '*':
        result = x * y;
        break;

        case '/':
        result = x / y;
        break;

        default:
        cout << "Improper operation. Please input a correct calculation         operation: \n";

     }
     return result;
}

...
...

string input;
if(!getline( cin, input ) ) return; //Try to read one line.

istringstream lin( input );
float partial = 0.0;
float a;
char op;
while(lin >> op >> a) partial = Input(partial, a, op);


//At this point, partial should contain your final result
```

Answer (score 0):

### Note: I have not tested cases. Like division by zero. etc

```
float operate(float a, char operand, float b)
{

    float result=0.0;

    switch(operand)
    {
        case '+':
            result = (a+b);
            break;

        case '*':
            result = (a*b);
            break;

        case '/':
            result = (a/b);
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Unknown operand"<<endl;
            break;
    }


    return result;

}


int main()
{   
    float result=0.0;
    char operand;
    float a,b;

    cout<<"enter a number followed by an operation, followed by a number"<<endl;


    while(cin>>a>>operand>>b)
         result+=operate(a,operand,b);

    cout<<result;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What if you have an odd number of numbers? On the other hand, your are assuming that each operation is added to the final result.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a little parser a few weeks ago, you can study my code and maybe (hopefully) you find something usefull.
its not c++, but c, so your compiler should be able to compile it.

the parser parses any statements that could be built by following rules:

```
<expression> ::= <term>
               | <term> "+" <term>
               | <term> "-" <term>

<term>       ::= <factor>
               | <factor> "*" <factor>
               | <factor> "/" <factor>

<factor>     ::= <number>
               | "(" <expression> ")"

<number>     ::= ["-"] ["0" .. "9"]*
```

here is the code, it is pretty much self explaining because it follows the rules defined above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char next;

void getNext(){
  next=getchar();
}

int getNum(){  //get a number
  int num=0;
  if((next<'0')||(next>'9')){
    printf("error: expected number; found %c",next);
    exit(-1);
  }
  while((next>='0')&&(next<='9')){
    num*=10;
    num+=(next-'0');
    getNext();
  }
  return num;
}

int add(int x){
  return x+term();
}
int sub(int x){
  return x-term();
}
int multiply(int x){
  return x*factor();
}
int divide(int x){
  return x/factor();
}

int factor(){
  int f=0;
  if(next=='('){
    getNext();
    f=expression();
    if(next=')')
      getNext();
    else{
      printf("error \")\" expected; found %c",next);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }else{
    f=getNum();
  }
  return f;
}

int term(){
  int val;
  val=factor();
  while((next=='*')||(next=='/')){
    char c=next;
    getNext();
    switch(c){
      case '*': val=multiply(val); break;
      case '/': val=divide(val); break;
      default: printf("error: (*, /) expected; found %c",next);
               exit(-1);
    }
  }
  return val;
}

int expression(){
  int sign=1;
  int val;
  if(next=='-'){
    sign=-1;
    getNext();
  }
  val=term()*sign;
  while((next=='+')||(next=='-')){
    char c=next;
    getNext();
    switch(c){
      case '+': val=add(val); break;
      case '-': val=sub(val); break;
      default: printf("error: (+, -) expected; found %c",next);
               exit(-1);
    }
  }
  return val;
}

int main(void) {
  getNext();
  printf("%d\n", expression());
  return 0;
}
```

example:

```
$ gcc main.c -o calc
$ ./calc
1+2+3           
6
$ ./calc
(1+2+3)/2
3
$ ./calc
3*(1+2)
9
$ ./calc
-10+20
10
$
```